# How to create a batch number after N rows of a similar type in Oracle Select SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have following data where I have treatment numbers and their respective customers. I want to make every treatment to have 3 customers and want to associate a batch ID. For example for T0001 3 customers will have a unique batch ID. And rest of 2 will have another batch ID. Similarly for T0002 there will be another batch ID which will have only those 2 customers. Means every batch will have maximum of 3 customers per treatment number.

**Current Table**

```
Treatment Number    Customer ID     
T00001              C01             
T00001              C02                 
T00001              C03             
T00001              C04                 
T00001              C05             
T00002              C06             
T00002              C07             
T00004              C09
```

**Required Result**

```
Treatment Number    Customer ID     Batch ID
T00001              C01             1
T00001              C02             1   
T00001              C03             1
T00001              C04             2   
T00001              C05             2
T00002              C06             3
T00002              C07             3
T00004              C09             4
```

Comment: could you also add the expected result table?

Comment: Your table has duplicate records for Treatment number and customerID combinations. There is not point in storing another column which does nothing but adds a common value to the already duplicated rows. The `customerid ,Treatment` combination should have been unique. But, it does not appear so from your sample data. Thus it takes a toll on the fundamental rdbms principles.

Comment: Moreover, you have not specified whether the batch should be assigned in a particular order or not. If there is no specific order with respect to customerid, according to which the batch id is to be incremented, please mention it clearly to avoid confusion.

Comment: @KaushikNayak I fixed that duplication. Customerid and Treatment will maintain uniqueness. My requirement is only to make batches per treatment. And to identify them with a batch Id. Since I have ordered by treatment then I want batches in the same order. So that treatment data remain together. Hope its clear.

Comment: @SerkanArslan I have made the edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would simply do arithmetic on `row_number()` to assign the batch id within each treatment:

```
select t.*,
       floor( (row_number() over (partition by treatment order by customer) - 1) / 3) as batch_id
from t;
```

Then, I would use `dense_rank()` to assign it globally:

```
select t.*, dense_rank() over (order by treatment, batch_id_within) as batch_id
from (select t.*,
             floor( (row_number() over (partition by treatment order by customer) - 1) / 3) as batch_id_within
      from t
     ) t
```

Answer (score 0):

First assign sequential number (starting with 0) to **each treatment** using `ROW_NUMBER` in the required order (I'm using the customer_id column).

Define the `BATCH_START` as **1** for each *row number* equal 0 or all rows with `mod(rn,3) = 0`.

Then simple calculate the `BATCH_ID` by *summing up* the `BATCH_START`.

Example

```
with cust2 as (
select 
TREATMENT_NUBMBER, CUSTOMER_ID,
row_number() over (partition by TREATMENT_NUBMBER order by CUSTOMER_ID)-1 rn
from cust),
cust3 as(
select TREATMENT_NUBMBER, CUSTOMER_ID,RN,
case when mod(rn,3) = 0 then 1 end BATCH_START
from cust2)
select TREATMENT_NUBMBER, CUSTOMER_ID, BATCH_START,
sum(BATCH_START) over (order by TREATMENT_NUBMBER, CUSTOMER_ID) BATCH_ID
from cust3
order by TREATMENT_NUBMBER, CUSTOMER_ID;

TREATM CUS BATCH_START   BATCH_ID
------ --- ----------- ----------
T00001 C01           1          1
T00001 C02                      1
T00001 C03                      1
T00001 C04           1          2
T00001 C04                      2
T00002 C04           1          3
T00002 C05                      3
```